# Can't Programatically fetch data with Apollo Client

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Most of the information out there about Apollo Client and GraphQL queries is about fetching data and immediately rendering something.

What about the common use case where I want to fetch data to, let say, update the state in which I clearly don't need to render JSX, I just want to run Javascript code.

Use the following code snippet as an example

```
onRefChange (formValues) {

    let { project, ref } = formValues
    let projectFound = find(this.state.projects, (o) => { return o.id === project.value } )

    let variables = {
      slug: projectFound.slug, ref: parseInt(ref)
    }
    console.info('variables ready', variables)
    return (
      <Query query={RESOLVE_REF} variables={variables}>
        { ({ data, error }) => {
          console.info('data response', data)
          console.info('error response', error)
          return data
        }}
      </Query>
    )
  }
```

Apollo forces me to use the `Query` component just to perform a query, even when I don't want to render anything. Also those `console.info` never log anything, but the variables ready text does appear.

I have found that the documentation is pretty clear on using the `Query` component, but obscure on every option which is different. I feel I'm missing something.

I'm also concerned about how Apollo doesn't seems respect the separation of responsibilities, apparently merging both data and presentation into a single responsibility (as is clear with the `Query` component), which in my current understanding is quite silly, but most likely I'm fucking things up.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you've configured and included an [ApolloProvider](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo#ApolloProvider) at the top of your component tree, you can get your query instance using either the [withApollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo#withApollo) HOC, or the [ApolloConsumer](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo#apollo-consumer):

```
const MyComponent = ({ client }) => {
 // use it!
}
withApollo(MyComponent)

<ApolloConsumer>
  {client => (
    // use it!
  )}
</ApolloConsumer>
```

You can then use any of the methods that are available to the client instance, including `query` and `mutation`, both of which return a Promise that resolves to an `ApolloQueryResult` object that includes `data` and `errors`. The full documentation for the client's API can be found [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client). Your code would then look something like:

```
async onRefChange (formValues) {
  let { project, ref } = formValues
  let projectFound = find(this.state.projects, (o) => { return o.id === project.value } )

  let variables = {
    slug: projectFound.slug, ref: parseInt(ref)
  }
  try {
    const { data } = await this.props.client(RESOLVE_REF, { variables })
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle errors
  }
}
```

Comment: Finally ended up going with the ApolloConsumer way. Thanks for your clarity.